ErrorWebExceptionHandler not working on springboot 3
we have a global exception handler implementing ErrorWebExceptionHandler
we use it in springboot 2 with webflux + kotlin. and it works fine .
But the same thing is not working when moved to springboot 3 with webflux
@Component
@Order(-2)
class RestExceptionHandler(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

  var log = logger()

  override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, ex: Throwable): Mono<Void> {
    // handle and return Mono Response 
    // sample return statment    
    return exchange.response.writeWith(
      Mono.just(
        exchange.response.bufferFactory().wrap(
          objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(
            objectMapper.readValue<ErrorItem>(ErrorItem(code, message))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

}



Many things changed in SpringBoot 3. WebExceptionHandler is now used instead of ErrorWebExceptionHandler. Also, you need to verify first if the response has been committed. This should work:
    override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, ex: Throwable): Mono<Void> {
    val response = exchange.response

    if (response.isCommitted) {
        return Mono.error(ex)
    }

    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

    val errorItem = when (ex) {
        is ResponseStatusException -> ErrorItem(ex.status.value(), ex.reason ?: "error")
        else -> ErrorItem(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.message ?: "Internal Server Error")
    }

    return response.writeWith(
        Mono.fromSupplier {
            val buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(errorItem))
            buffer
        }
    )
    }

